# How do I find and replace words in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin that is used to find and replace words. So far I have this code and it does not seem to work.

```
function replace_content($content){

   $wp_post = get_the_content();

   $content = str_replace('lorem',' ronny',$wp_post);

   return $content;

}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Please define `it does not seem to work`

Comment: it does not seem to perform it desired task. Search and replace.

Comment: That's not defining. He means, what is the expected output and what is the actual output/error messages/anything other than "it does not work"

Comment: the code should actually search for the word lorem in the content and replace it with ronny. So far it doesn't.

Comment: @Ronny What if you removed `$wp_post = get_the_content();` and used `$content = str_replace('lorem',' ronny', $content);`

Comment: Thanks HamZa, but it still didn't replace it.

Comment: I know how `str_replace()` works, but what is the actual output?

Comment: @PRPGFerret The content remains the same. No replacements occured.

Comment: @Ronny I meant to try something like [this](http://pastebin.com/jMXFvG9w). According to [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), it should work. If it didn't then there is something else going on.

Comment: @HamZa that did not work either. No replacements

Comment: @Ronny Can you paste in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) the data in question ?

Comment: oh! finally figured out the problem. the content was in capital letters so i should have used str_ireplace to ignore the capital letter

Comment: @Ronny See ... Btw [php 6.0 should introduce E_DOESNT_WORK and E_LOLWUT](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=10722135#10722135)

Comment: @Ronny Post it as an answer. It does not make sense to post the answer in the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. The content was in capital letters, so i used the `str_ireplace()` instead of `str_replace()` function so as to ignore case.